# Design Hours of Operation SQL Table

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

I am designing a SQL table to store hours of operation for stores.

Some stores have very simple hours:  Monday to Sunday from 9:30AM to 10:00PM

Others are little more complicated. Please consider the following scenario:

```
Monday:  Open All Day
Tuesday: 7:30AM – 2:30PM & 4:15PM – 11:00 PM 
Wednesday: 7:00PM – 12:30 AM (technically closing on Thursday morning)
Thursday: 9:00AM – 6:00PM
Friday: closed.
```

How would you design the table(s)?

**EDIT**

The hours will be used to showing if a store is open at a user selected time.

A different table can probably handle any exceptions, such as holidays.

The store hours will not change from week to week.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A table like this would be easy for both the output you posted, as well as just firing a bit back (open? yes/no):

```
Store | Day | Open | Closed
---------------------------
1     | 1   | 0000 | 2400
1     | 2   | 0730 | 1430
1     | 2   | 1615 | 2300
...
```

Features:

1. Using 24-hour isn't necessary, but makes math easier.
2. Store ID would presumably join to a lookup table where you stored Store information
3. Day ID would translate to day of week (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, etc.)

To query for your dataset, just:
`SELECT Day, Open, Close...`  (you'd want to format Open/Close obviously)

To query IsOpen?, just:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @desiredtime BETWEEN Open AND Closed THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM table 
WHERE store = @Store
```

Answer (score 3):

Think of it more as defining time frames, days / weeks are more complex, because they have rules and defined start and stops.

**How would you define a timeframe?**

***one constraint** (Start[Time and Day])*, ***one reference*** 'Duration' (hours, minutes,.. of the span)*.  Now the shifts (timeframes) can span multiple days and you don't have to work complex logic to extract and use the data in calculations.

```
**Store_Hours**

Store | Day | Open | DURATION
---------------------------
1     | 1   | 0000 | 24
1     | 2   | 0730 | 7
1     | 2   | 1615 | 6.75
... 
1     | 3   | 1900 | 5.5
```

Comment: I was also considering duration, but it might be more difficult to determine if a store is open at 1:00 AM on Monday. We need to check both Sunday and Monday

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN @desiredtime BETWEEN Open AND DateAdd(hh, duration,Open)THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM table WHERE store = @Store` Not hard?

Comment: the statement is little more complicated. We need the day as well, so we need to check both the desired day, and the previous day in case the duration starches into today. So if we are checking for day =1, we also need to check if day=7 has a case when open + duration >24.

Comment: Either case your goig to need to do that.  But if you don't use duration.  How are you going to tell the deference between Wed/Thr and Sun/Mon?  One instance the shift carries over, the other a shift ends and another begins.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to do more than just store and display it?

I think a design which needs to tell if a store is open at a particular time would have to be informed by all of the possibilities, otherwise, you will end up not being able to accommodate something.

What about holiday exceptions?

I would consider storing them as intervals based on a base time (minutes since time 0 on a week).

So 0 is midnight on Monday.

Interval 1 would be 0 - 1440

Interval 2 would be 1890 - 2310

etc.

You could easily convert a user selected time into a minute offset and determine if a store was open.

Your only problem remaining would be interpretation in display for friendly display (probably some extensive logic, but not impossible) and overlap at time 10080 -> 0.

Comment: We will store the holiday exceptions in a different table.

Comment: We will use the hours to see if a store is open at a user selected time, so it is not just for displaying back on the screen.